# save content in file using golang

Tags: go

I can't understand why I need to have second condition in the picture.Is it possible to a not exists error? What does the expression

```
 "_, err = os.Stat(fp)"
```

do?

```
// Stat returns a FileInfo describing the named file.
// If there is an error, it will be of type *PathError.
```

it is the explanation of the expression "_, err = os.Stat(fp)"

Answer (score 0):

[`PathError`](https://pkg.go.dev/io/fs#PathError) has a field `Error`, which can be `ErrNotExist` among other things. Because `PathError` implements the method `Unwrap`, you can check that [idiomatically](https://pkg.go.dev/errors#pkg-overview):

```
_, err := os.Stat(p)
if err != nil {
  notExist := errors.Is(err, fs.ErrNotExist)
  // ...
}
```

Comment: thx，I have understanded it